# What is the easier way (no libraries, no 100KB of JavaScript) to read value from the blockchain?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I'm working on an open-source project.

I'm hesitant to include web3.js with all the code.

I just want to read a single value from the Ethereum blockchain.

That is why my requirement is to avoid 100KB libraries.

Comment: The problem is that it's not so straightforward. You either have to use some external service (such as Etherscan API) or then query a node directly. If you want to query a node directly you need to run your own node or have access to some shared node (Infura for example) - all of that is much easier with libraries.

Comment: You can use [Etherscan Developers APIs](https://etherscan.io/apis), then you'll just need to `require("request")`.

Comment: Thanks, using Etherscan API should be simple enough, can make a web request without involving any libraries. Trusted 3rd party kind of sucks but it's a reasonable risk-reward ratio, nothing too critical.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a HTTP POST request to a geth or parity node.

Here is the documentation with examples using `curl`: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Instead of `curl`, just use a HTTP request and POST the data.

You'll need to make sure your local node allows connections. I use this something like this: `geth --rpcapi eth,net,web3 --rpccorsdomain * --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0`